# Spring Boot app deployed on cloud run removes "message" details from HTTP errors in REST

Tags: spring-boot, google-cloud-run

Please help me understand what's going on under the hood. I can't figure out the reason why my java spring boot app deployed on Cloud Run removes "message" details from http errors in REST API.

Here is the super simple test app that I did just to confirm nothing else affect it:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class SandboxApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SandboxApplication.class, args);
    }
    
    
    @RestController
    public class MyRestController {
        
        @GetMapping(value = "/test", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
        public String testMethod() {            
            throw new ResponseStatusException(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST, "Test Method Error Message");
        }
        
    }
    

}
```

Response I get running it locally (expected):

```
{
  "timestamp": "2020-06-24T20:09:39.138+00:00",
  "status": 400,
  "error": "Bad Request",
  "message": "Test Method Error Message",
  "path": "/test"
}
```

But when I deploy it to Cloud Run and run the same app, I get it like that (see that "message" information is empty):

```
{
  "timestamp": "2020-06-24T20:10:23.531+00:00",
  "status": 400,
  "error": "Bad Request",
  "message": "",
  "path": "/test"
}
```

I will keep this test app running for a while here - https://rfg-sandbox-jihqciukfq-uc.a.run.app/test

Comment: Can you share your dependencies?

Comment: I suspect that this issue may be coming from your application (specifically from Spring boot) rather than form Cloud Run itself. Please share a complete minimal reproducible example with your complete application and the Dockerfile